# How to know whether a potentiometer is a linear potentiometer or audio potentiometer?

Tags: datasheet, potentiometer

In general, how can you tell?

As a specific example, how would I know from looking at the following datasheet? http://www.alps.com/products/WebObjects/catalog.woa/E/HTML/Potentiometer/RotaryPotentiometers/RK09K/RK09K1130AV7.html

Comment: Related / Possible Duplicate: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50218/whats-the-difference-between-linear-and-audio-tapers-and-why-should-i-care

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relationship between the angle of the knob and the resistance is the "taper". That datasheet says this pot's taper is "1B".

Finding information on what 1B means is a bit tricky. It's at the [related information](http://www.alps.com/products/WebObjects/catalog.woa/E/HTML/Potentiometer/RotaryPotentiometers/RK09K/RK09K_common.html) link at the top. The tapers are described at the very bottom. Here's the relevant image:

[image: pot tapers]

It's hard to read, but 1B is the straight line in the upper-left. This is an ordinary linear pot.

This is something of an industry convention. See for example [Alpha's pot tapers](http://www.alpha-products.com/cd_catalog/new_catalogs/Pots/tapers.htm). By convention, anything with a "B" in it is a linear taper. Anything with "A" in it is "audio" or "logarithmic".